# How can I use 2 gpu to calculate in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use two GTX 980 gpu.
When I am dealing with slim in tensorflow.
Usually, i have a problem so called 'Out of Memory'.
So, I want to use two gpu at the same time.
How can I use 2 gpu?
Oh, sorry for my poor english skill. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to run TensorFlow on multiple GPUs, you can construct your model in a multi-tower fashion where each tower is assigned to a different GPU. For example:

```
 # Creates a graph.
c = []
for d in ['/gpu:2', '/gpu:3']:
  with tf.device(d):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3])
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2])
    c.append(tf.matmul(a, b))
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  sum = tf.add_n(c)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(sum))
```

You will see the following output.

```
    Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: Tesla K20m, pci bus
id: 0000:02:00.0
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:1 -> device: 1, name: Tesla K20m, pci bus
id: 0000:03:00.0
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2 -> device: 2, name: Tesla K20m, pci bus
id: 0000:83:00.0
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:3 -> device: 3, name: Tesla K20m, pci bus
id: 0000:84:00.0
Const_3: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:3
Const_2: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:3
MatMul_1: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:3
Const_1: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2
Const: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2
MatMul: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2
AddN: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
[[  44.   56.]
 [  98.  128.]]
```

I'm not sure with "Out of Memory" issues since u didn't give snippet of code.

Answer (score 0):

By default, if the GPU version of TensorFlow is installed, TensorFlow will use all the GPU available.

To control the GPU memory allocation, you can use the `tf.ConfigProto().gpu_options`.